# Rendering JSON in a RAZOR view in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, json.net

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC app. My app is interacting with a third-party REST service. That service is getting called in the controller of my MVC app. The results from the service look like this:

```
{  
  "group@odata.type": "#Collection",  
  "group": [],  
  "class@odata.type": "#Collection",  
  "class":[    
    { "total": 111, "value": "A" },
    { "total": 222, "value": "B" },
    { "total": 333, "value": "C" }
  ],  

  "status@odata.type": "#Collection",
  "status": [    
    { "total": 1, "value": "Open" },    
    { "total": 20, "value": "Closed" },    
    { "total": 51, "value": "Unknown" }
  ]  
}
```

The results of the service are stored in a `JObject` property in my model called `Results`. For every array, I am trying to print out its key name. Then, I want to look through and print out each value and total in the array. In other words, the JSON above would look like this:

```
group

class
  A - 111
  B - 222
  C - 333

status
  Open - 1
  Closed - 20
  Unknown - 51
```

In an attempt to do this, I have the following in my View.

```
foreach (var result in Model.Results)
{
  <div></div>
  <ul>
    @foreach (var subResult in result.?)
    {
      <li style="padding-left:8px;">@(subResult["value"] + " - " + subResult["total"])</li>
    }
  </ul>
}
```

Clearly the above doesn't work. My challenge is, I do not understand how to:

1. Loop through the key/value pairs in a JObject.
2. Identify if the value is a JArray or another JObject.

If I use `result.Children()`, I do not get each key/value pair like I'm expecting. At the same time, `result` does not have a `Keys` property like I would expect. I feel very stuck at the moment.

Thank you for any help you can provide. Happy holidays!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) on `JObject`, it should implement `IDictionary<string, JToken>`. They might have done an explicit implementation of the interface, so you'd need to cast your JObject instance to `IDictionary<string, JToken>` first.

Answer (score 0):

First of all define some classes that correspond to your Json response:

```
public class ServiceResponce
{
    public IList<Row> Group{get;set;}
    public IList<Row> Class{get;set;}
    public IList<Row> Status{get;set;}
}

public class Row
{
   public int Total {get;set;}
   public string Value {get;set;}
}
```

Than you can use [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/json) or some other library to deserialize your Json in to an object:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServiceResponce>(json);
```

So your model will finally have `ServiceResponce` property:

```
public ServiceResponce Result{get;set;}
```

Than you can easily navigate through ServiceResponce properies:

```
<div></div>
<ul>
foreach (var result in Model.Result.Group)
{
    <li style="padding-left:8px;">@(result.Value + " - " + result.Total)</li>
}
<ul>
```

To make it cleaner write an HtmlHelper that receives a `IList<Row>` as a parameter and renders it in a required format, so at the end you will end with something like:

```
@YourHelper(Model.Result.Group)
@YourHelper(Model.Result.Class)
@YourHelper(Model.Result.Status)
```